# ACL permissions failing in ubuntu

Tags: access-control-list, ubuntu-14.04, permissions

**Problem**

I need to give read/write access to a system group called "mongodb" on a USB key that's been formatted as ext4. 
It seems that the command worked, but when I try to have the system user write to this folder, I get a permissions error:

```
2014-11-11T10:41:19.326-0500 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/media/me/mongotest/mongodb", terminating
```

Here's the command I used to check that this group has access:

```
me@medev:~$ getfacl /media/me/mongotest/mongodb/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/me/mongotest/mongodb/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:mongodb:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

**Additional Test**

Just to prove it was working, I did the following:

1. create a new user in ubuntu called "test".
2. created a new group called testers
3. added test to testers.
4. added testers to ACL list for /media/me/mongotest/mongodb folder on the usb:

> ```
>  me@medev:~$ getfacl /media/me/mongotest/mongodb/
>  getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
>  # file: media/me/mongotest/mongodb/
>  # owner: root
>  # group: root
>  user::rwx
>  group::r-x
>  group:mongodb:rwx
>  group:testers:rwx
>  mask::rwx
>  other::r-x
> ```

5. Then I changed user to "test":

> ```
> me@medev:~$ su test
> Password:
> ```

6. Tried to change directories into the USB key like so:

> ```
> test@medev:/home/me$ cd /media/me/mongotest
> bash: cd: /media/me/mongotest: Permission denied
> test@medev:/home/me$ cd /media/me/mongotest/mongodb
> bash: cd: /media/me/mongotest/mongodb: Permission denied
> test@medev:/home/me$
> ```

So it would seem that I'm doing something wrong with the way I'm creating / adding these permissions... because it's failing for both users / groups.

Answer (score 0):

I had to grant the ACL permissions on the /media/me folder. 
"me" is the name of my profile / username and I guess ubuntu mounts by default under my name. 
so this is what I did:

setfacl -m g:mondodb:rwx /media/me

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Always use a nonuser mount point.
So mean a user (mongodb) cant write (me) other user files or links.
If you delete "me" user creating a error of related user and services.
When you give a folder more than 1 user, you make a cross link(s).
Never a service offer you use a cross link.

***sorry for bad language..